# Is it typo or has hidden meaning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading 'A book of set theory (Charles.C.Pinter)'

In exercise 2.5.6 
$$\prod_{i \in I}A_i \cap \prod_{j \in J}B_j =\prod_{(i,j) \in I \times J}A_i \cap B_j$$
where  $$\prod_{i \in I}A_i$$ is infinite product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

If $f$ is an element of $$\prod_{i \in I}A_i \cap \prod_{j \in J}B_j$$ $domf=I$ and $domf=J$ But how function $f$ can become an element of $$\prod_{(i,j) \in I \times J}A_i \cap B_j$$ because $dom f\neq I\times J$

Moreover problem asks to prove this$$\prod_{i \in I}A_i \cup \prod_{j \in J}B_j =\prod_{(i,j) \in I \times J}A_i \cup B_j$$

is that just typo or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Is it $\prod$ or $\coprod$? Some authors use $\coprod$ for disjoint union.

Comment: @bof maybe $\prod$ .There was no $\coprod$ notation so far in this book

Comment: Yes, there is a hidden meaning. But it can only be read by a Lotus Level 5 Megapriest.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider a special case and see if it makes sense:
$$
(A_1 \times A_2) \cap(B_1 \times B_2) =
(A_1 \cap B_1) \times (A_1 \cap B_2) \times (A_2 \cap B_1) \times (A_2 \cap B_2)
$$
So I would say: NO it is not right.  Not even if $I=J$.

Answer (score 0):

For $I = J$:
$$\prod_{i\in I}A_i \cap \prod_{i\in I}B_i = \prod_{i\in I}A_i\cap B_i.$$
because 
$$
f\in\prod_{i\in I}A_i \cap \prod_{i\in I}B_i\iff\forall i\in I:\ f(i)\in A_i\land\forall i\in I:\ f(i)\in B_i\iff$$
$$\iff\forall i\in I: f(i)\in A_i\cap B_i\iff\prod_{i\in I}A_i\cap B_i.
$$